# icacls on windows server 19 doesn't seem to work

Tags: openssh, icacls

First, I'm not a windows expert.  Also, windows people that I've talked to do not seem to be familiar with "icacls", which I thought was strange.  I found it via search.
I see someone asked a similar question but it never received an answer.  I'm hoping by providing a specific example that it might mean something to someone.
Trying to remove permissions without using the gui, why does this seem to have no effect?
(specific names changed for security):

```
domain\testsftp@SERVER1 C:\Users\testsftp\.ssh>icacls authorized_keys
authorized_keys NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                DOMAIN\TESTSFTP:(I)(F)
                DOMAIN\dal123:(I)(F)
                DOMAIN\adm_j123:(I)(F)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

```
domain\testsftp@SERVER1 C:\Users\testsftp\.ssh>icacls authorized_keys /remove "DOMAIN\dal123"
processed file: authorized_keys
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

```
domain\testsftp@SERVER1 C:\Users\testsftp\.ssh>icacls authorized_keys
authorized_keys NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                DOMAIN\TESTSFTP:(I)(F)
                DOMAIN\dal123:(I)(F)
                DOMAIN\adm_j123:(I)(F)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

domain\testsftp@SERVER1 C:\Users\testsftp\.ssh>
```

It says it was successful, but nothing changed.  Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ACL entry cannot be removed because it is *inherited* `(I)` from a parent directory, rather than being directly added to the file. The only ways to get rid of it are:

- remove the user from *the parent directory*, where it was originally defined (if you run icacls on the directory, it should show the entry as inheritable `(OI)(CI)` but *not* as inherited `(I)` – if it still shows as inherited, try one more level up);
- or disable `/inheritance` on the file (or the parent .ssh directory), converting all inherited ACEs into directly editable ones, and *then* `/remove` the unwanted ACL entry from the file;
- or add an explicit `/deny` ACE, on the file (or the parent directory). This won't get rid of the unwanted 'allow' ACE, but will make it ineffective as direct deny always has higher priority than inherited allow. (But it probably won't satisfy OpenSSH.)

This is not specific to icacls – the GUI has the same restrictions and will not let you remove inherited access entries unless you click "Disable inheritance" first.

In your particular case it sounds like the two users are meant to have access to the entire C:\Users\testsftp, so if you don't want to remove them, you can disable inheritance on the .ssh subdirectory (or just on the authorized_keys file if you want).